# Cannot insert a record for ManyToMany relation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, many-to-many

I know there are numerous posts about this problem and I've tried their solutions yet still couldn't solve my problem. I've started a Spring Boot application and it is connected to a postgesql db. I have two classes named Student and Course. I want to create a ManyToMany relation between them. When I run the application it creates the tables as I wanted. And also if I insert a record for course_student table, I can display the courses that a student takes. But I can append a new course for a student nothing happens.

**Student class**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.ALL,
        },
        mappedBy = "students"
    )
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

**Course class**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL,
        }
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name = "course_student",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "course_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") }
    )
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

**IStudentRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface IStudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

**SqlStudentService class**

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.models.Course;
import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import com.example.demo.repositories.IStudentRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service("SqlStudentService")
public class SqlStudentService implements IStudentService {
    private final IStudentRepository studentRepository;

    public SqlStudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
    }

    public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Student insertStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public Student updateStudent(Long id, Student student) {
        Student oldStudent = getStudentById(id);

        if (oldStudent != null) {
            oldStudent.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
            oldStudent.setLastName(student.getLastName());

            return studentRepository.save(oldStudent);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteStudentById(Long id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void addStudentToCourse(Course course, Long studentId) {
        Student student = getStudentById(studentId);

        if (student != null) {
            student.getCourses().add(course);
            studentRepository.save(student);
        }
    }
}
```

All of other functions in SqlStudentService class work properly but addStudentToCourse method does not. I've return the Student object after the student.getCourses().add(course); line. The course added successfully. But it is not added to that record to course_student table. Do you have any idea what I am missing? Thank you so much.

Comment: have u try using ICourseRepository? because seen to me the many to many table is declared in course class

Comment: Thank you @Erwin. I move the declaration to Student class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "course_student", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "course_id_fk", referencedColumnName   ="course_id_pk") },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = 
   "student_id_fk",referencedColumnName="student_id_pk") })

private Set<Student> students;
```

You don't have to use Cascading Type =All and fetch type as it is lazy default